# Strange 1px space randomly appearing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a setup like this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrrVrV

On Chrome at various display resolutions or zooms (ctrl+ / ctrl-),
there'll appear a 1px space between `#two`'s border and `#three`, showing the red background of `#two`
The 1px space will either appear in all 4 sides, top+bottom, or left+right.

I've toyed around with this for a few hours now and the only thing that'll completely eliminate this behavior is removing `box-sizing: border-box` which unfortunately will break a lot of things.

Think this is a Chrome-only issue as I've yet to be able to replicate it in Firefox or Opera.

Any idea what's causing it?